# Can not read the data from HDFS in pySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs

I am a beginner in coding. Currently trying to read a file (which was imported to HDFS using sqoop) with the help of pyspark. The spark job is not progressing and my jupyter  pyspark kernel is like stuck. I am not sure whether I used the correct way to import the file to hdfs and whether the code used to read the file with spark is correct or not.
**The sqoop import code I used is as follows**

*sqoop import  --connect jdbc:mysql://upgraddetest.cyaielc9bmnf.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/testdatabase --table SRC_ATM_TRANS --username student --password STUDENT123  --target-dir /user/root/Spar_Nord  -m 1*

**The pyspark code I used is**

*df = spark.read.csv("/user/root/Spar_Nord/part-m-00000", header = False, inferSchema = True)*

Also please advice how we can know the file type that we imported with sqoop? I just assumed .csv and wrote the pyspark code.

Appreciate a quick help.

Answer (score 0):

When pulling data into HDFS via sqoop, the default delimiter is the tab character. Sqoop creates a generic delimited text file based on the parameters passed into the sqoop command. To make the file output with a comma delimiter to match a generic csv format, you should add:

```
--fields-terminated-by <char>
```

So your sqoop command would look like:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://upgraddetest.cyaielc9bmnf.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/testdatabase --table SRC_ATM_TRANS --username student --password STUDENT123 --fields-terminated-by ',' --target-dir /user/root/Spar_Nord -m 1
```